# Creating smaller sized grid and interpolating data from bigger grid

Tags: qgis, python, interpolation

I am working with a vector grid that looks like this:

[image]

I am not very experienced with QGIS and have been looking for a way to divide each mesh of the grid a certain amount of time to get a `smaller grid` like this:

[image]

Instead of a 6x6 grid I would have a 12x12 grid. I then would like to `interpolate` each cells value with each other to get a nice gradient instead of something that is so pixelated. I am not even sure interpolation is the right term here...?

Is there a way of doing so with `QGIS`? I could work with `python` too if it's needed or if there is an easier way with it.